# How to fix multi choise with powerapp

Tags: powerapps, sharepoint-list

I have this code in the gallery
If i dont use all i just what thouse results. But i dont get them right.

```
Filter(Möbler; 

Or(IsBlank(DropdownKategori.Selected); 
Kategori.Value = DropdownKategori.Selected.Value

&& 

IsBlank(DropdownSubKategori.Selected); 
SubKategori.Value = DropdownSubKategori.Selected.Value

&& 

IsBlank(DropdownColor.Selected); 
Color.Value = DropdownColor.Selected.Value

&& 

Bokad.Value = "Nej"
)
)
```

This is the default.
[image]

**The picture under**
You see a part of the data here where is say
Bokad(Booked)
Ja/Nej (Yes/No)
So it should never show 2 of them The one that say Ja should never been shown.
[image]

And another part of this is when i choose

```
kategory = Stol
Undergroup / underkategory =  pinnastol 
color = all
```

it give me the right answer. Dont know if this just a situation but it does this right.

[image]

But when i add the
Färg/Color = Svart/Black when it show al the Black and not just the "stol" and "pinnastol". But this time not the bokade/Booked

[image]

anyone have any idee why this happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
Filter(
  Möbler;
  Bokad.Value = "Nej";
  IsBlank(DropdownKategori.Selected) Or Kategori.Value = DropdownKategori.Selected.Value;
  IsBlank(DropdownSubKategori.Selected) Or
SubKategori.Value = DropdownSubKategori.Selected.Value;
  IsBlank(DropdownColor.Selected) Or Color.Value = DropdownColor.Selected.Value
)
```

Comment: This is amazing you dont know how thankfull im for this answer ♥